# Continue after HttpWebRequest response returns 404 error

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebresponse

I need to determine if a list of users are in a 3rd party user directory.  I am writing the method in C#.NET 4.0. The user list is over 2700 entries. The API to access this user directory uses REST to return the user information.  If the user is not in the directory, response to the HttpWebRequest is a 404 error. I catch the WebException error.

The problem is I can only get the user information for 1 user at a time so I would like to do a for loop to go thru the user list.  However, when the 404 error occurs, it breaks out of the loop.  Is there any way to catch the 404 error and continue the loop with the next user?

This is my code:

```
    public void GetRecipientDataFromCortext()
{
    SqlConnection SqlConn = null;
    CortextUser objCortextResult;
    try
    {
        string strStoredProcedure = "PagingToolGetRecipientsAndDevices";
        DataTable tdtRecipientData = new DataTable("RecipientData");
        //Create a datatable to store final results
        DataTable tdtCortextResultData = new DataTable("CortextResults");
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("RecipientID", typeof(int));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("DeviceTypeID", typeof(int));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("DeviceAddress", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("CUID", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("InviteStatus", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("IsEnabled", typeof(bool));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("MiddleName", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("HonorificPrefix", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("HonorificSuffix", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("Mobile", typeof(string));
        tdtCortextResultData.Columns.Add("Pager", typeof(string));

        string strSqlConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CONNECTION_STRING].ConnectionString;
        //Get the recipient list from the database
        using (SqlConn = new SqlConnection(strSqlConnection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strStoredProcedure, SqlConn))
            {
                SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlConn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataReturned = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd))
                {
                    dataReturned.Fill(tdtRecipientData);                         
                }
            }
        }
        //For loop to make a call to cortext to get properties of this device 
        string tstrPropertyValue = string.Empty;
        string tstrProperty = string.Empty;
        int tiDeviceTypeID;
        int tiRecipientID;

        //This is the for loop to check each recipient to see if he/she is in the directory
        foreach (DataRow row in tdtRecipientData.Rows)
        {               
            tstrPropertyValue = row["Address"].ToString();
            tiDeviceTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(row["DeviceTypeID"].ToString());
            tiRecipientID = Convert.ToInt32(row["RecipientID"].ToString());

            //Insert into the Cortext table initial values first
            //This inserts into a database table the user to check.
            //This table is used to get the initial recipient list. 
            //Any users in this table are not in the list.
            InsertCortextInformation(tiRecipientID, tiDeviceTypeID, tstrPropertyValue);

            switch (tiDeviceTypeID)
            {
                case 1:
                    tstrProperty = "mobile";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tstrProperty = "email";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tstrProperty = "pager";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            //Results from cortext call add to data table
            //User not in the directory results in this method call to return a 404 error.
            //Exception breaks out of the loop
            objCortextResult = GetCortextUserInformation(tstrProperty, tstrPropertyValue);
            //Add results to datatable
            DataRow newRow = tdtCortextResultData.NewRow();
            newRow["RecipientID"] = Convert.ToInt32(row["RecipientID"].ToString());
            newRow["DeviceTypeID"] = Convert.ToInt32(row["DeviceTypeID"].ToString());
            newRow["DeviceAddress"] = row["Address"].ToString();
            newRow["CUID"] = objCortextResult.CUID;
            newRow["InviteStatus"] = objCortextResult.inviteStatus;
            newRow["IsEnabled"] = objCortextResult.isEnabled;
            newRow["FirstName"] = objCortextResult.userFirstName;
            newRow["LastName"] = objCortextResult.userLastName;
            newRow["MiddleName"] = objCortextResult.userMiddleName;
            newRow["HonorificPrefix"] = objCortextResult.userHonorificPrefix;
            newRow["HonorificSuffix"] = objCortextResult.userHonorificSuffix;
            newRow["Email"] = objCortextResult.email;
            newRow["Mobile"] = objCortextResult.mobile;
            newRow["Pager"] = objCortextResult.pager;

            tdtCortextResultData.Rows.Add(newRow);

        }

        //Insert data table results into Paging Tool table, PagingToolCortextInfo
        int tiRecID, tiDeviceID;
        bool tbIsEnabled;
        foreach (DataRow row in tdtCortextResultData.Rows)
        {
            tiRecID = Convert.ToInt32(row["RecipientID"].ToString());
            tiDeviceID = Convert.ToInt32(row["DeviceTypeID"].ToString());
            tbIsEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(row["IsEnabled"].ToString());
            UpdateCortextInformation(tiRecID, tiDeviceID, row["DeviceAddress"].ToString(),
                                        row["CUID"].ToString(), row["InviteStatus"].ToString(), tbIsEnabled,
                                        row["FirstName"].ToString(), row["LastName"].ToString(), row["MiddleName"].ToString(),
                                        row["HonorificPrefix"].ToString(), row["HonorificSuffix"].ToString(),
                                        row["Email"].ToString(), row["Mobile"].ToString(), row["Pager"].ToString());
        }

    }
    //Catches the HttpWebResponse errors like 404
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            string errorMessage = string.Format("Error code: {0} ", httpResponse.StatusCode);
            //         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
            using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    errorMessage += text;
                    //
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
                    logger.ErrorException(errorMessage, e);
                }
            }
        }
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.ErrorException(ex.Message, ex);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (SqlConn != null)
        {
            SqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there any way to continue in the for loop after the call Http response returns a 404 error and get the next user?

I would like to acknowledge the 404 error and continue in the for loop to get all of the users.

Thanks.

Comment: Place a `try{}catch{}` scoping out the method which throws an exception.

Comment: I have the `WebException` catch that catches the 404 error.  My problem is that it throws me out the for loop and I can't get the next user.  How can I avoid getting out of the for loop when the 404 error is thrown?  I would like to acknowledge the error and continue in the loop.

Comment: Place a `try{}catch{}` **inside your loop** scoping out the method which throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily with your code :)

Wrap the line:

```
objCortextResult = GetCortextUserInformation(tstrProperty, tstrPropertyValue);
```

in the try catch:

```
var isNotFound = false;
try {
    objCortextResult = GetCortextUserInformation(tstrProperty, tstrPropertyValue);
}
catch(WebException ex) {
    if(((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)       
    {
        isNotFound = true;
    }
    else {
        throw;
    }
}

if (isNotFound) continue;

...
```

The continue for the Status Code 404 will enter the next iteration of your loop and achieve the desired behaviour.

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a try!

Comment: If my previous code did not work for you, the edit above should. Further thought makes me think that the 'continue' will only work in the main scope of the loop and not in the 'catch' statement.

Comment: The first code did work.  It hit the `continue` when there was a 404 error and got the next user.  Thanks a million!